# TypeError: user.save is not a function.how can i solve

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update the value of the name of the user as shown below in code, but getting a type error. can you help me to solve this error?

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/test", {
        useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true
    })
        .then(
            result => { console.log("connected...") }
        )
        .catch(
            err => { console.log(err) }
        )
        const Schema = mongoose.Schema
    const addressSchema = {
        houseNo: Number,
        street: String,
        state: String,
        district: String
    }
    const userSchema = new Schema(
        {
            name: String,
            password: String,
            email: [String],
            address: [addressSchema]
        }
    )
    const UserModel = mongoose.model('user', userSchema)
    const addressModel = mongoose.model('address', addressSchema)
    async function update(){
        let user= UserModel.findById('5f535047dfa8ae2c9cc2c97f')
    user.name="vaghsiya"
    user= await user.save()
    console.log(user)enter code here
    }
    update()
```

Comment: First go through this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the `findById` method to return the `user` object, before calling the `save`. Add an await in front for the `findById`

```js
let user = await UserModel.findById('5f535047dfa8ae2c9cc2c97f');
```